# Using GRPC with Eclipse and protobuf-dt

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers, protobuf-dt

I have an existing eclipse project (not maven or gradle,) which uses protoc to compile proto files. It uses the protobuf-dt plugin in eclipse and generates the java files from the .proto files whenever you modify them.

For a new requirement I'm adding a GRPC service to the project, however I can't find any way in protobuf-dt to add the GRPC plugin to the command. How do I set up this automatic generation of java from proto supporting GRPC services?